# TTGO T-Beam V1.0 GPS not sending data: programming error or hardware failure?

Tags: gps, esp32

I have TTGO T-Beam V1.0. First I experimented with Meshtastic and everything seemed to be working fine, including GPS.

Later I flashed MySondy GO firmware (to observe weather probes data), which does not use GPS at all.

Now I again changed firmware, this time it is LoRa APRS tracker (https://github.com/oe3cjb/TTGO-T-Beam-LoRa-APRS). Although the program reports "GPS OK!" when it starts (I have yet to check how does it find out), GPS never gives a fix.

The problem is not related to known issue of not powering GPS, because the program properly initializes AXP192 PMU and I checked with a voltmeter that there is 3.3 volts on Vcc pin of Neo6M module. Also, the red LED near Neo will start blinking with 1 second interval when the antenna is exposed for some time, so the Neo chip seems to be working (but the program even in this situation reports "zero satellites", probably because it receives no data at all from GPS).

I added a 2-line "probe" into the GPS reading function in the program hoping that I would see raw data from GPS copied to USB serial port.

The following are relevant sections from `TTGO_T-Beam_LoRa_APRS.ino` sketch, where I added a "probe" to see what's coming from the GPS:

```c
// Pins for GPS
#ifdef T_BEAM_V1_0
   static const int RXPin = 12, TXPin = 34;  //  34: Neo6M TxD, 12: Neo6M RxD
#else
   static const int RXPin = 15, TXPin = 12;  
#endif

...

HardwareSerial ss(1);        // TTGO has HW serial
TinyGPSPlus gps;             // The TinyGPS++ object

...

static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600; //GPS

...

void setup()
{

...

  Serial.begin(115200);

  ...

    ss.begin(GPSBaud, SERIAL_8N1, TXPin, RXPin);        //Startup HW serial for GPS

  ...
}

static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  char c ;
  do
  {
    if (tracker_mode != WX_FIXED) {
      while (ss.available()) {
        c = ss.read();
        gps.encode(c);
        Serial.write(c); // here --> nothing ever seen in serial monitor
      }
    }
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}
```

However, it seems there are never any data coming from serial port (pins 34 and 12) connected to GPS module. At least the sketch should copy any incoming characters to the USB serial port, but nothing appears there.

So I am thinking about likely causes:

- I mapped the wrong port
- the baud rate is wrong (unlikely, as ESP32 would at least receive some garbage bytes)
- UART1 in ESP32 is dead
- UART in Neo6M is dead
- Neo6M got somehow reconfigured not to send any data out to UART

How could I verify what has happened? Is it possible to "factory reset" Neo 6M chip somehow?
Unfortunately, official TTGO documentation is next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I experience same problem so tk see if UART's are OK I reprogrammed with Meshtastic and GPS data all again working fine.
To my opinion I would think your last mentioned option is the right one.
Also waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know TTGO has hardware serial or hardware serial is the same as serial or not. but i declare GPS to use Serial1

`#define GPS_RX 34`
`#define GPS_TX 12`
`Serial1.begin(GPSBaud, SERIAL_8N1, GPS_RX, GPS_TX);`

`static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)`
`{`
`unsigned long start = millis();`
`do`
`{`
`while (Serial1.available())`
`gps.encode(Serial1.read());`
`} while (millis() - start < ms);`
`}`

and that's all

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but maybe more information.

I've also had this problem where the GPS flashes as if its working, but no data is coming through. I first started by flashing on the code from [this tutorial](https://www.aeq-web.com/ttgo-lilygo-esp32-gps-lora-board-lmic-otta-source-code/?lang=en) - I'm now trying to flash the board with code from this [github repository](https://github.com/kizniche/ttgo-tbeam-ttn-tracker)

From the u-blox [datasheet](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/NEO-6_DataSheet_(GPS.G6-HW-09005).pdf) if pins 14 and 15 are held high at boot it should start sending through data at 9600 bps immediately after start up. Probing these pins - as well as TX and RX (pins 20 and 21 on the GPS module) - shows the config pins are correctly set high, but there is no data on the serial bus; even if the tx and rx pins on the esp8266 are set to high impedance.

Not sure why the GPS module isn't sending data, but I suspect I've managed to change the GPS settings by using random code

My T-Beam GPS worked when I first used the board. Now I'm taunted by that little red flashing LED!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reset my GPS using the u-blox studio and some dodgy soldering. It's now come back to life.

I've thrown together this Arduino script which should give the same result (untested).

```
#include "Wire.h"

#define SERIAL1_RX 34
#define SERIAL1_TX 12

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("GPS RESET");
  delay(2000);
  Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, SERIAL1_RX, SERIAL1_TX);
  byte reset_message[]={0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x09, 0x0D, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
                        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
                        0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x1C, 0x9B
                        };
  Serial1.write(reset_message, sizeof(reset_message));
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());
    Serial1.println();
  }
}
```

Comment if there are any issues and I can answer with how to do it using u-blox software